# Is multithreading possible in Jfreechart?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to create a dataset for my chart, which will be updated once a second. But I'm using ssh commands to get data. For example, when I call an `sar -n DEV 1 1` on a remote machine, it responses after 3 seconds. I'm calling 5-6 commands serially like this, so it takes a long time to update my chart. So I need to send these commands in threads, so I can wait shorter than I did before. I'm not a professional in threading in Java.

Here is an example code:

```
public Mygraph()// my constructor function, it puts some components for my form.
{
    // some code

    timer = new Timer(FAST, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            TimePeriod period = new Second();

            for (int j = 0; j < PARAM.length; j++) {

                String sonuc = PRS.Pars1(SES.CONNECTION, "sar -n DEV 1 1 | grep -wF  " + SUTUN
                        + " | awk '{ print $" + PARAM[j] + " }' | tail -1");

                String sutun = PRS.Pars1(SES.CONNECTION,
                        "sar -n DEV 1 1 | grep IFACE | tail -1 | awk '{ print $" + PARAM[j]
                                + " }'");

                // i need to get these "sonuc" and "sutun" variables
                // concurrently above. Because each command takes 2-3
                // seconds to execute.
                dataset.add(period, Double.parseDouble(sonuc), sutun);

                if (dataset.getItemCount() > COUNT) {
                    TimePeriod firstItemTime = dataset.getTimePeriod(0);
                    dataset.remove(firstItemTime, sutun);

                }
            }

        }

    });

    // some code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

JFreeChart is *not* thread safe. Just like any other AWT/Swing component, any updates to JFreeChart should be done on the EDT.

That being said, you could (and probably should) put your loading on a different thread, and only update your chart (on the EDT) *after* you've loaded the whole dataset.

Comment: +1 JFreeChart is based on AWT, but rest is correctly described == should be `Just like any other AWT/Swing component, ...`

Comment: Actually not to nitpick, but it looks like JFreeChart is at least partially built on Swing. For example, ChartPanel extends JPanel:  http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html

Comment: Is there an example about your suggestion?

Comment: You can probably find a generalized example for processing some data on another thread and using SwingUtilities.invokeLater() to update a gui with the processed data on the EDT. You might also check out the Swing Concurrency tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/